# android: how to compress assets directory using apktool

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I recently have a requirement that I need to use apktool to decode an apk file,then replace some files in assets directory with other files. Now question is that the recompiled apk file is bigger than before(the original apk is about 50MB, the decompiled apk is about 150MB, but the files I replaced are just a little bit bigger than before) while I am using `apktool.exe b XXX` command to recompile. So in this situation, Is there some solutions to solve this?

ps:apktool version 2.1.1. These files include xx.pkm files which are encrypted picture. According to http://ponystyle.com/blog/2010/03/26/dealing-with-asset-compression-in-Android-apps/, extension pkm should be compressed while apktool didn't.

Comment: I'd report a bug to the project as this isn't normal behavior. - https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool

Comment: Finally, I found version 2.0.2 can avoid this problem.